# How to add the objects to an array using push?

Tags: javascript, angular6, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

I am trying the push the multiple selected items as an array, but am getting the error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

---

```
payload: Array<any>;

runRequests() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DashboardDialogComponent, {
      width: '280px', height: 'auto', data: { title: 'Run Now', details: 'Submit the request to run immediately' }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.selection.selected.forEach(element => {
          const request = { 'reqId': element.reqId, 'runAt': this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'H:mm:ssZZZ") };
          this.payload.push(request); //I am getting error in this line, 
        });
        this.store.dispatch(new requestDashboardActions.RunNow(this.payload));
      }
    });
  }
```

---

Comment: Payload is currently undefined, you've only typed it. `payload: Array<any> = [];`

Comment: your payload variable is undefined, you should assing initial value, like []

Comment: try to log `typeof this.payload` where you getting that error

Comment: i think you have a scope issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to intialize the property:

```
payload: Array<any> = []
```

If you check the transpiled javascript file, there won't be a property called `payload` unless you intialize it with an empty array `[]`

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20check%20the%20trasnpile%20code%2C%20it%20only%20has%20payload2%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload2%3A%20Array%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

**Update:**

I assumed it was property of the class. If it's just a local variable, just remove the `this` keyword.

```
payload.push(request)
```

Comment: Yes i gave that

Comment: No you need to intialize it with an empty array `[]`

Comment: Yes i have initialized with an empty array, still am getting the error.

Comment: try without `this`

Comment: @MadhuL is `payload` a property of the class or just a local variable?

Comment: It's a local variable

Comment: @MadhuL then remove the keyword `this`. `this` refers to the instance of the class. For local variables you don't need that. How is it not throwing error for you? You have not used `var`, `let` or `const`

Comment: Cannot find name 'payload'.

Comment: @MadhuL Then you're not sharing all the information. If it's a property, the former should work. If it's local variable second soltion should work (Which is unlikely considering you have not used `var`, `let`, `const`)

Comment: i gave as  const payload: Array<any> = []; and now am getting this error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      const payload: Array<any> = [];
      if (result) {
        this.selection.selected.forEach(element => {
          const request = { 'reqId': element.reqId, 'runAt': this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'H:mm:ssZZZ") };
          payload.push(request);
        });
        this.store.dispatch(new requestDashboardActions.RunNow(payload));

Comment: You're probably getting that error in the earlier line: `this.selection.selected.forEach`

Comment: Yes, but earlier am nt getting this

Comment: @MadhuL eh? How does that happen? I'm not sure.

Comment: Now am able to add the object to array but am getting the error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: @MadhuL Put multiple breakpoints at `if (result)` and below and check the values of `this.selection.selected` and the like

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a initial value to

```
 payload: Array<any> = []
```

if you don't assign JS will implicitly assign a value `undefined` to it and `undefined` don't have `push` method.